# How to remove flickering white pixels/fireflies from Unreal Engine render

Tags: rendering, unreal-5, noise

I'm currently rendering an archviz scene in UE5.1 lit by lumen, but I'm struggling to remove these pesky over-bright pixels on areas which are very reflective or metallic:
[image]

I have tried turning off Bloom, upping the samples for reflectivity, translucency and GI, upping the temporal and spatial samples but it doesn't seem to make a difference aside from resulting in longer render times... anyone know how to get rid of them?